# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable using Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I created a test class using TestNG and in this class I defined 5 test methods. When I run the test, the TestNG console shows that 3 scenarios of the total of 5 have been executed (see the image below).
[image: Image description here]
The registroNovo and tabulacaoTratamento methods are not executed.
When I close the browser (Chrome) the TestNG console displays the following error screen that follows below.

[image]

Eclipse console displays the following error message:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.8.0', revision: '924c4067df', time: '2017-11-30T11:36:59.109Z'
System info: host: 'RJO-BCC-C2A-H21', ip: '10.5.79.38', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6..., userDataDir: C:\Users\lsnpere\AppData\Lo...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 67.0.3396.87, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 32d0291ab5ecaa1141f9997771edcd95
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.alert(RemoteWebDriver.java:987)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$28.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:808)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$28.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:804)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at page.RegistroNovo.registroNovo(RegistroNovo.java:25)
    at test.ValidarFaturamentoRoamingTest.registroNovo(ValidarFaturamentoRoamingTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Has anyone ever seen this kind of error?

Basically I created 4 classes:

The **BaseTest** class which has all methods that are common to all test classes:

```
public class BaseTest {

public static WebDriver driver;
public static WebDriverWait wait;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "e:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() throws InterruptedException {

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("mn_sair"));
    driver.quit();

}}
```

The test class **ValidarFaturamentoRoamingTest** which extends the class **BaseTest**:

```
public class ValidarFaturamentoRoamingTest extends BaseTest {

@Test(priority=0)
public void acessarBkoMais() {

    HomePage homepage = new HomePage(driver, wait);
    homepage.abrirBkoMais();
}
@Test(priority=1)
public void logarBkoMais() {

    LoginPage logar = new LoginPage(driver, wait);
    logar.loginBkoMais("000000", "000000");
}
@Test(priority=2)
public void logarEstrategia() {

    LogarEstrategiaPage logarEstrategia = new LogarEstrategiaPage(driver, wait);
    logarEstrategia.logarEstrategia();  
}
@Test(priority=3)
public void registroNovo() {
    RegistroNovo registroNovo = new RegistroNovo(driver, wait);
    registroNovo.registroNovo();
}
@Test(priority=4)
public void tabulacaoTratamento() {

    TratOsFatRoamPage rt = new TratOsFatRoamPage(driver, wait);
    rt.TratOsFatRoam();     
}}
```

The class **TratOsFatRoamPage** which extends the class **BasePage**.

```
public class TratOsFatRoamPage extends BasePage {

public TratOsFatRoamPage(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {

    super(driver, wait);

}

String idMotivo = "cboMotivo";
String idSubMotivo = "cboSubMotivo";
String idStatus = "cboStatus";
String qtdNumerosFaturas = "txtQtdFaturas";
String qtdNumerosCotas = "txtQtdContas";
String idObservacao = "txtObservacao";
String idSalvar = "btnSalvar";

public void TratOsFatRoam() {

    writeText(By.id(qtdNumerosFaturas),"Teste 2018");
    writeText(By.id(qtdNumerosCotas), "2018-2");

}}
```

And the class **BasePage** which has all the methods that are common classes:

```
public class BasePage {

public WebDriver driver;
public WebDriverWait wait;

public BasePage(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {

    this.driver = driver;
    this.wait = wait;

}

public void click(By elementLocation) {

    driver.findElement(elementLocation).click();
}

public void writeText(By elementLocation, String text) {

    driver.findElement(elementLocation).sendKeys(text);

}

public String readText(By elementLocation) {

    return driver.findElement(elementLocation).getText();

}

public void selectText(By elementLocation, String value) {

    Select atividade = new Select(driver.findElement(elementLocation));
    atividade.selectByValue(value);

}}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "When I close the browser (Chrome)..."? Did you close it while the tests are running? If so, why would you do that?

Comment: In the last 2 tests the script hangs and nothing happens. When I close the browser, the Eclipse console displays the error message. The error message only happens when the browser is closed. Before that, everything is stopped.

Comment: I was able to find out the source of the problem. The reason for the other methods not being executed was due to a condition I made to check when a JavaScript alert is displayed. Script checks if an alert is displayed. If it were, the accept command is triggered.
The problem is that I did not put an else saying what should be done if the alert was not displayed. So the Script kept waiting for the alert to appear.
Thank you all for trying to help me!

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to communicate with the **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browsing** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.40*
- You are using *chrome=67.0*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.8.0** of **2017-11-30T11:36:59.109Z** which is almost *six months* older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty **ancient**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u131* , *Selenium Client v3.8.0* , *ChromeDriver v2.40* and *Chrome Browser v67.0*

Comment: ...and yet 3 of the 5 tests pass?

Comment: Hello JeffC.Yes!

Answer (score 0):

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable

This means that for some reason there is no communication happening between driver and chrome instance; in your case that reason is you are closing it manually after 3 Tests are run.
and your TestNG console displays the error screen because last 2 test cases weren't run due to closing of browser.

### So here your real issue is what is taking second last test to take time?

For that post some code.